# local pointer variables

Tags: c, pointers

What will be the output of the following program?

```
int *call();

void main() {
  int *ptr = call();
  printf("%d : %u",*ptr,ptr);
  clrscr();
  printf("%d",*ptr);
}

int *call() {
  int x = 25;
  ++x;
  //printf("%d : %u",x,&x);
  return &x;
}
```

Expected Output: Garbage value 

Actual Output: 26 #someaddr

Since x is a local variable it's scope ends within the function call. I found this code as an example for dangling pointer.

Comment: The program exhibits undefined behavior, for the reason you mention. What is your question? You expected anything and you got something.

Comment: Sure with: "ptr=call(); " ? Is not "ptr=call; "?

Comment: Actually, in this context, 26 is a garbage value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the output of this function is undefined. As you already pointed out the scope of x ends with the function. But the memory where 26 has been written is not used agian. So printing this value will give 26. If this memory is used again, it could be anything.

Answer (score 2):

its **Undefined behaviour**

since at x scope is dead after returning from call() so the pointer to that variable you can not use ahaed

BY COMPILING YOUR program you will get following error

```
warning: function returns address of local variable
```

**if your program since give output 26 since its undefined behaviour. You should no do this at all.**

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, you have entered the `Undefined Behavior` valley. You can't predict what would be any value. Even if the value makes some sense, ignore it.